# ImportError: cannot import 'get_db' from i partially initialized module 'blog.db', how can i fix it

Tags: python, flask

i have the import error:

> from blog.db import get_db cannot import get_db

I have my structure files like this

```
worskpace/
  blogger/
     blog/
       _init__.py
       db.py
       insertData.py
```

and I'm importing like this

```
from blog.db import get_db
```

db.py file have this

this is de fucntion i want to import

```
def get_db():
    """
    This is my database engine to cloud firestore
    """

    if 'db' not in g:
       cred = credentials.Certificate("key.json")
       firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
       g.db = firestore.client()


   return g.db
```

Comment: Which file is the import in, and what file is `blog.db` in?

Comment: blog is the folder where I have my python files, and db es the file where i have my databse logic, so i want to import the get_db function to insert data and Im doing it like above: from blog.db import get_db

Comment: As @M-Chen-3 asked, where is the file that contains that import statement?  You'll have a better chance at a useful answer if you show us what is in db.py.

Comment: oh my bad letr me show you guys

Comment: Did you try `from db import get_db`?